# How to add IP route(s) So Kubernetes cluster addresses go via through appropriate adapter

Tags: kubernetes, routes, weave, cni

I have installed `Kubernetes cluster`(`one Master and one Worker- Node`) on `CentOS-8 OS` stand-alone server separately as per the below link instructions.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-centos-8/

`Weave-Net - CNI plugin installed` as per above link.  Now I can see below new network adapter in our K8s Master & Worker-Node server.

```
weave: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1376
inet 10.32.0.1 netmask 255.240.0.0 broadcast 10.47.255.255
inet6 fe80::a07d:21ff:fef1:4656 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether a2:7d:21:f1:46:56 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 141 bytes 13322 (13.0 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 48 bytes 4896 (4.7 KiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

But the problem is from host server unable to `ping (Or) access any of our remote site/location IPs` (ping response given below). whereas `Local IPs are pinging & accessible`.

```
ping -c 4 120.121.5.48
PING 120.121.5.48 (120.121.5.48) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.32.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.32.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.32.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.32.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 120.121.5.48 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
pipe 4
```

Also from host server tried to connect our remote `LDAP server through telnet` it shows below error message.

```
# telnet 120.121.5.48 389
Trying 120.121.5.48...
telnet: connect to address 120.121.5.48: No route to host
```

In our `K8s Master` & `Worker-Node server` have `23 network adapters`, `Statically network IP` have configured, So any additional configuration need to be configured for K8s CNI reachable in default routing?

`ip route show` & `route -n` output as follows.

```
# ip route show
default via 45.46.47.1 dev ens1f0 proto static metric 100
10.32.0.0/12 dev weave proto kernel scope link src 10.32.0.1
45.46.47.0/24 dev ens1f0 proto kernel scope link src 45.46.47.48 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         45.46.47.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens1f0
10.32.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     10     0        0 ens1f0
10.32.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 weave
45.46.47.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens1f0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Tried to change the weave route to default with below command. it executed successfully, But still same problem.

```
ip route add 10.32.0.0/24 via 45.46.47.1 dev ens1f0 metric 100
```

Suppose if i run `ifconfig weave down` everything is working fine. But to use Kubernetes cluster i need `Weave-net network adapter`. So please help me to add IP route(s) So that my Kubernetes cluster addresses go via through appropriate adapter, So that i will be able to access both our local & remote location server.

Comment: Can you ping remote IPs directly from the nodes, though?

Comment: No. Not pinging in both master & worker.

Comment: Then it's probably not related to Kubernetes, but with your node network configuration.

Comment: Ok.So any additional configuration I need to do for routing weave adapter IP with default route?

Comment: No, Your weave adapter is most likely running correctly. What @BogdanL is trying to explain is: If Your host machines that k8s nodes are running on can't connect to specific external network resource the same will happen from inside the k8s cluster. So You need to fix Your host machine network configuration.

Comment: Yes, weave adapter running fine. My Kubernetes cluster in order to go through default adapter tried below command.
'ip route add 10.32.0.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev em3 metric 0'
But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the `CNI-Weave-Net` plugin to `Flannel`, now it is working as excepted.